# Extending wxAny for known types [wxWidgets]

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Is it possible to extend the capabilities of wxAny in an application for a limited set of types when it is known that wxAny will only hold one of those types?

Specifically, I would like to use wxAny to hold one of `int`, `float`, `double`, `wxString` or `wxDateTime`. It could be okay to only represent numbers by `double` and make the conversion elsewhere.

The only functions that I need to implement are `operator<`, `operator==` and `operator>` with both parameters as wxAny for sorting, and finding max / min values.

The obvious thing is to subclass `wxAny` to `wxSome` and use `wxAny::CheckType` to branch different comparison methods for the different types. The reason I hesitate to do this is because the wxAny methods are not virtual, which leads me to think that wxAny is not intended to be subclassed.

This is to do with some updates to the wxFreeChart library and so I would like to only have the same level of dependencies as the standard wxWidgets library.

Comment: maybe use std::variant

Comment: Sorry, I should stated that this is for the wxFreeChart charting library and I am trying to keep the same dependencies as wxWidgets itself. Updated now.

Comment: @iwbnwif, why not use templates?

Comment: @Igor Good question, not easy to answer! In part because I have substantially completed what I set out to do with wxAny, therefore I wanted to see whether it is possible to do the next step with it too. Also, a templated implementation would by nature recreate quite a bit of what is already implemented in wxAny.

Answer (score 1):

Let's read the question backwards.

"`wxAny` methods are not `virtual`, which leads me to think that `wxAny` is not intended to be subclassed". Indeed. C++ is not a pure OO language, and in fact OO is not even the default. `virtual` is a vital part of Liskov substitutability, but methods are only `virtual` if you explicitly make them.

"The obvious thing is to subclass `wxAny`". That would be obvious in pure OO languages without free functions. In pure OO languages, every function belongs to a class. And since you can't add functions to `wxAny`, you add them to a subclass. But as noted, C++ is not just OO, it has free functions. `bool compare(wxAny,wxAny)` is a valid function declaration.

That said, `I would like to hold one of ...` suggests that you're using `wxAny` as an implementation detail. Perhaps you should have a wrapper class, which has a `wxAny` *member*. In that case, you'd name the comparator `bool Wrapper::operator<(Wrapper rhs) const`.

Comment: >Perhaps you should have a wrapper class, which has a wxAny member ...  - Actually, I already do, in fact 3 wrappers from a common base. > In that case, you'd name the comparator... - Yes, that is definitely what I should do - thanks!! (_composition over inheritance_ - right?) My only concern is that I will need to define which part of the wrapper is compared (some have multiple wxAny members).

Comment: Composition is related - a wrapper would just have that one `wxAny` member, but impose the invariant that it contains just one of those 4 types. This is easy to do with just 4 overloaded constructors, for instance. Your class that now has multiple `wxAny` members would then have multiple members of that wrapper class, each holding one `wxAny` member.

Comment: Ah, I think I've got it. Let me paraphrase to confirm I understand correctly. My so-called `wxSome` class would have one wxAny member, 4 ctors and 4 groups of comparison operators. I would then have `wxSome` members in my classes in place of the existing `wxAny` members.

Comment: @iwbnwif, well this is in essence what I suggested - go with the templates.

Comment: @iwbnwif: Close. You'd have 4+1 comparators - `private` ones for each type, and a public one that figures out which of the 4 private ones is needed. Still, what to do with `wxSome(1.0) < wxSome("five")` ? PS. `wxSome` would be a reasonable name for a wxWidgets type. But you're not writing a new wxWidgets class; use your own prefix for your own types. Or better, use a `namespace`. (It should have been `wx::Any`)

Comment: You're right, `wxSome` was a tongue-in-cheek name. I was thinking along the lines of `Orderable`. `Orderable(1.0) < Orderable("five")` is clearly an error and should raise one.